# save file from internet to hard disc in mac osx using objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos, url, download

How can I download file from internet in mac osx using objective c.I tried using `copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:` method in `NSFileManager` but did not worked.The domain is public so no authentication needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSFileManager` doesn't support HTTP URLs.  You'll need to use the [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003755) class to perform the HTTP request.

If you want to perform a synchronous HTTP request (e.g. for a console application or on a background thread of a GUI application), then the basic workflow is:

1. Construct an [`NSURLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for your desired URL
2. Call [`+[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003755)
3. Call [`-[NSFileManager createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to save the resulting `NSData` to your desired destination file.

If you need to do an asynchronous request, it's a little more complicated.  In that case, you'd create an object which conforms to the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol, set that as the delegate of an `NSURLConnection` object, and perform the request.  When it completes, you then save it to the file system as above.  The details are left as an exercise for the reader.